# What is the affine ring of $\mathbb{P}^1_K - P$ where $P$ is a closed but possibly non-$K$-rational point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field, and let $P\in\mathbb{P}^1_K$ be a closed point. If $P$ is a $K$-rational point, then $\mathbb{P}^1_K - P = \text{Spec }K[x]$.

In general I believe $\mathbb{P}^1_K - P$ is still affine. How can we describe its affine ring?

Comment: Pick one $b \in P, L = K(b) \cong K[t]/(h(t))$, let $\gamma(x) = b+\frac{1}{x-b}\in L(x)$ obtaining $\mathbb{P}^1_L- P =\gamma( \mathbb{A}^1_L - Q) \cong  \mathbb{A}^1_L - Q= Spec(L[x]_{(q(x))}) = Spec(K[t,x]/(h(t))_{(q(t,x))})$ which is affine over $K$ but not the same as $\mathbb{P}^1_{K}- P$

Answer (score 2):

I claim that $P=(F)$ for an irreducible homogeneous polynomial $F\in K[x,y]$, and that therefore $\Bbb{P}^1_K-P=D_+(F)$ is in fact a distinguished open affine.

To see this, consider the affine cones involved. The affine cone of $\Bbb{P}^1_K$ is just $\Bbb{A}^2_K$, and the affine cone of $P$ will have codimension 1 in $\Bbb{A}^2$, and is therefore an irreducible hypersurface. Thus to show that the ideal of $P$ is generated by a single homogeneous element, it suffices to show that irreducible hypersurfaces in $\Bbb{A}^2$ are cut out by a single element.

Consider the ideal $(f,g)\subseteq K[x,y]$, with $f\nmid g$ and $g\nmid f$. If $\gcd(f,g)\ne 1$, then there is an irreducible $\pi$ with $\pi \mid f$ and $\pi \mid g$, and then we have that $(f,g)\subseteq (\pi)$, however $\pi$ cuts out an irreducible hypersurface, as does $(f,g)$, so we have in fact that $(f,g)=(\pi)$. On the other hand, if $\gcd(f,g)=1$, then working in $K(x)[y]$, we have that $Af+Bg=1$ for $A,B\in K(x)[y]$, or $af+bg=p(x)$, with $a,b\in K[x,y]$ and $p\in K[x]$ by clearing denominators. Similarly, there is $a',b'\in K[x,y]$ and $q\in K[y]$ with $a'f+b'g=q(y)$. Then we have that $(K[x]/(p))[y]/(q)$ is finite dimensional over $K$, and $(p(x),q(y))\subseteq (f,g)$, so $K[x,y]/(f,g)$ is finite dimensional over $K$, hence Artinian, and hence $\operatorname{Spec} K[x,y]/(f,g)$ is $0$ dimensional, contradicting our assumption that $(f,g)$ cut out an irreducible hypersurface. Thus all irreducible hypersurfaces in $\Bbb{A}^2_K$ are cut out by a single irreducible polynomial.

As a result, this implies that the affine cone of $P$ in $\Bbb{A}^2(K)$ is cut out by a single homogeneous polynomial, $F$, and $\Bbb{P}^1_K-P=D_+(F) = \operatorname{Spec} ((K[x,y]_F)_0)$

Comment: Could you give a definition of the affine cone? Hartshorne only defines them geometrically for algebraically closed fields, which is explicitly not the case here.

Comment: If $X = \operatorname{Proj} R$, then the affine cone on $X$ is $\operatorname{Spec} R$.

Comment: @red_trumpet, As KReiser says, the affine cone of $\operatorname{Proj} R$ is $\operatorname{Spec} R$.

Comment: @KReiser: How is this well-defined? There might be different rings $R \neq S$ such that $\text{Proj} R \cong \text{Proj} S$. Or shoould it be $\text{Spec}(\Gamma_*(\mathcal{O}_X))$?

Comment: @red_trumpet it does depend on the graded ring you use to form $\Proj R$, so technically we should speak of the as affine cone with respect to that graded ring. However, projective space has a standard graded ring used to define it. And yes, if you are just given a projective scheme, that would give you a graded ring you could use to form the affine cone, but I don't think there's a good reason to forbid the other possible affine cones, corresponding to other choices of graded ring.